# SDL Web 8.5 Storage Extension: Differentiating Republishing and Unpublishing in Remove Method

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, storage-extensions

We are implementing a Storage Extension using SDL Web 8.5.

The `remove` method is invoked while unpublishing an item, but this method is also invoked while republishing an already published item (afterwards the `create` method is invoked). This is strange as one would expect the `update` method to be invoked instead of `remove` and `create`. Apparently this is a known behavior as I see in [How do I get my Storage Extension to call the 'update' method when republishing a Dynamic Component Presentation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/how-do-i-get-my-storage-extension-to-call-the-update-method-when-republishing)?).

When I posted [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17685/storage-extension-differentiating-republishing-and-unpublishing-in-remove-metho) question for Tridion 2013 SP1, `LocalThreadTransaction.get().getDeployerTransaction().getDeployerAction()` was the answer and it worked OK. But the same is not working in SDL Web 8.5.

How can I find out within the `remove` method if it is invoked in the context of unpublishing or republishing? We have got a reason why we need to differentiate these 2.